# Attaining 100% in SNES and N64 Mario Games

Tags: super-mario-64, super-mario-world, paper-mario

In Mario games on the GameCube (eg *Mario Sunshine* or *Paper Mario: The Thousand Year Door*), it is possible to complete the game, beat the final boss, and attain 100% completion and save such that the load-game-screen shows *100%* or *120 stars*, etc. However for the same games on the SNES and N64 (ie, *Super Mario World*, *Mario 64*, and *Paper Mario*), I cannot figure out a way to attain 100% completion because after the final boss is beaten, the games hang on the final screen after the credits instead of returning to the title-screen/menu where the player can save post-final-boss.

Is this correct or is there a way to save a 100% game?

Comment: Hmm, some genius down–voted-and-ran. I guess that I can only theories that they don’t like to complete games.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Obtaining Completion Credit

For SMW and SM64, there is no way to save the game after beating the final boss, nor is it necessary. The game automatically credits the save file for the progress gained by beating the final boss.

I am unsure about Paper Mario, but I would imagine that it followed a similar mechanic of crediting you automatically.

### Completion Qualification

#### Super Mario World

The indicator that you have beaten every level (both in their normal ways and via finding their secret exits) is indicated on the load screen with a star beside the number of levels you have beaten. You receive this star upon finding 96 different level exits/bosses:

[image: Super Mario World Completion]

#### Super Mario 64

100% completion is denoted by collecting 120 stars. This is actually shown on the load screen when you complete the game:

[image: Super Mario 64 Completion]

#### Paper Mario

100% completion is achieved by obtaining all badges, star pieces, and recipes.

Comment: I forget if Paper Mario even has a postgame - a lot of RPGs didn't back then!  You saved before the last boss and you liked it, goddamnit!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I’ll have to re-check my save games (as soon as I can pull out my SNES and N64).

Comment: 100% in Paper Mario would mean obtaining a) all badges b) all star pieces and c) all recipes d) tattling all enemies (the latter is not logged though, so it's up to you to decide whether this is necessary)

Comment: @Zommuter Thanks for the data. I added it to the answer.

Comment: `The indicator that you have beaten every level (both in their normal ways and via finding their secret exits) is indicated on the load screen with a star beside the number of levels you have beaten. You receive this star upon finding 96 different level exits/bosses:`   Unfortunately that doesn’t help because I can’t figure out which ones I have yet to do. Is there some sort of indicator of completed/incomplete areas? I thought that  red/yellow/flashing was an indicator, but it doesn’t seem to because some areas are red, others yellow, most flashing, but I cannot figure out how to get past 95.

Comment: @Synetech Yellow dot levels have one exit, red dot ones two (including Star Road, where the casual exit is actually just roundway to the level itself), and IIRC all but one ghost houses also have a secret exit. And I'm not sure whether that one level on chocolate island where the second/third part depends on time doesn't even have _three_ exits

Comment: @Zommuter, thanks for the tip, I’ll keep an eye out for that the next time I have it out.

Comment: @Synetech You're welcome. Maybe you can find the missing exit [here](http://www.mariowiki.com/Super_Mario_World#Worlds) - I think I missed the one from illusion forest's ghost house last time, merely leading back to the first level

Comment: From my experience (and maybe I missed some obvious way of doing it), getting the key on the last ghost house (in valley of bowser) was a pain in the neck and not at all necessary to get anywhere (see e.g. the map on the top right of Zommuter's link)